# TypeError when testing with Jest and Formidable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, formidable

I have wrote a cusom express middleware to pars an incoming multipart form.
The middleware works fine when launched in local or deployed but the test with jest fails with the error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property domain of [object process] which has only a getter
```

The issues seems to come from the package [asap](https://github.com/kriskowal/asap#readme)  used by formidable.

I think that Jest is putting some limitations on the process object since the line where everything breaks is

```js
domain.active = process.domain = null;
```

in the file raw.js

Does anyone has any workaround or solution for this issue? I cannot migrate to formidable V3 at the moment so that's not an option